React window.scrollTo not working on route change
I’m working on a React app using react-router-dom. I want the page to scroll to the top every time the route changes. Here’s what I’ve tried:
Used a custom hook with useEffect:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const useScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Attempting to scroll to top"); // Logs correctly
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "auto",
    });
    console.log("Scroll executed"); // Also logs correctly
  }, [pathname]);
};

export default useScrollToTop;

Added the hook in my App.tsx:
import useScrollToTop from './hooks/useScrollToTop';

const App = () => {
  useScrollToTop();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* My routes */}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

Verified that window.scrollTo executes (logs appear), but the page doesn’t scroll to the top.
I also tested with:
a. useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect. 
b. Forcing a delay using setTimeout.
c. Checking for scrollable elements (html, body, or a custom container). 
d. CSS fixes like ensuring html, body { height: auto; overflow: visible; }. 
e. Despite all this, the page still doesn’t scroll to the top. Is there anything I’m missing or any interference I should check for?

Issue
Your custom hook is clearly being called outside the router:
const App = () => {
  useScrollToTop(); // <-- needs routing context
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> // <-- provides routing context
      <Routes>
        {/* My routes */}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

So it can't possibly have access to the routing context that BrowserRouter provides to the useLocation hook and all other RRD hooks and components called/rendered within its sub-ReactTree, e.g. its children.
In fact, there should be a console error about that useLocation hook call:

Solution Suggestion
Move the useScrollToTop hook to a component rendered within the router so that it can properly access the routing context.
Below I have just converted the hook into a React component so that it is renderable as JSX within the router and able to call side-effects.
Example:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "auto",
    });
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>   // <-- provides routing context
      <ScrollToTop /> // <-- can access routing context
      <Routes>
        {/* My routes */}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};


Is it ScrollToTop or useScrollToTop here const ScrollToTop = () => { ?

@flash ScrollToTop, a React component, so it can be rendered as a component within the router. Sorry, I've updated to make that part clearer.

It doesn't work. I believe i tried this solution before.

@flash Is the window scrollable? It's entirely possible that you are rendering content that fills the screen and it renders some scrollable element. That element would need to be "scrolled to top". Does this make sense? Can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] of your actual code?
